# temporary folder into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, deployment

I am developing a Java application with Eclipse and under Apache Tomcat. 
when I load an image it puts it in this directory : `C:\wamp\www.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myproject\`.

If I want to display the image I should refresh the directory (images) in Eclipse.

Does that happen only when I use Eclipse? And if I deploy the project, will the image be loaded always in this folder or in any folder?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Tomcat project with Eclipse, you have a special folder where you can copy your web resources to, e.g. images, CSS files, and the like.

When you deploy your web application, Eclipse will package it correctly to make sure the images and CSS get copied over.

Make sure you use relative paths, not absolute paths. Also I would recommend you write a maven script or ant script to handle packaging and deployment instead of using Eclipse. It is cleaner and you understand better how things work.